# How can I set quotas for /var/log/journal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, quota

On Ubuntu, `/var/log/journal` grows too large. I am told I can safely delete `/var/log/journal/*` but I'd rather have a quota set.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Edit [/etc/systemd/journald.conf](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/systemd/journald.conf.5.en.html):

- To set a total limit for all journal files, specify it in `SystemMaxUse=`.
- To set a limit for individual files (and enforce more frequent rotation), use `SystemMaxFileSize=`.
- Run `journalctl --vacuum` to enforce new limits.

For example:

```
[Journal]
# Total limit for all journals:
SystemMaxUse=4G
# Limit for individual files before rotation:
SystemMaxFileSize=1G
```

Comment: journalctl: option '--vacuum' is ambiguous; possibilities: '--vacuum-size' '--vacuum-files' '--vacuum-time'

Comment: My mistake, I thought they had added an option to automatically apply new journald.conf limits. I guess you'll have to use one of the manual options it offers you. Or possibly `--rotate` might do the job, as limits are generally applied during log rotation.

Comment: As the manual page says these days, journald.conf shows the compiled-in defaults, and one can just leave it alone and create e.g. /etc/systemd/journald.conf.d/local-maxuse.conf for local modifications.

Comment: Also, journalctl: option '--vacuum' is ambiguous; possibilities: '--vacuum-size' '--vacuum-files' '--vacuum-time'